# Mongodb: Populate a query with subdocuments and do also the opposite

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema of a Classroom

```
const Schema_CLASSI = mongoose.Schema({
    course: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

And a schema of students:

```
const Schema_ALUNNI = mongoose.Schema({
    classe_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CLASSI_collezione' },
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
```

How do I query and get a list like this

Class_1
Student_1
Student_2
Student_3
Class_2
Student_4
Student_5
Student_6
Class_3
Student_7

It is somenthing like a population but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to figure out what you are trying to do

```
const Schema_CLASSI = mongoose.Schema({
    course: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

then you saying my student collection has the link to many classes

```
const Schema_ALUNNI = mongoose.Schema({
    classe_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CLASSI_collezione' },
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
```

well the solution would be to have an array of students in each class something like

```
const Schema_CLASSI = mongoose.Schema({
    course: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
   student_ids: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CLASSI_collezione' }],
});
```

a kind one to many relationship

Remember that population is not particularly efficient method, you could look into aggregation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

you could also have a subdocument approach
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Hope it helps

Balint